# MariaDB 10.4.4 "exists" problem

Tags: mariadb

I have 2 similar queries:

1st with 0.002s execution time

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1`
WHERE (`order_id` = 1234
       OR (EXISTS
             (SELECT *
              FROM `accounts`
              WHERE `table1`.`member_id` = `accounts`.`id` )
           AND EXISTS
             (SELECT *
              FROM `accounts`
              WHERE `accounts`.`name` = 'test' )))
ORDER BY `table1`.`id`
```

and 2nd with 2.5s execution time

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1`
WHERE (`order_id` = 1234
       OR EXISTS
         (SELECT *
          FROM `accounts`
          WHERE `table1`.`member_id` = `accounts`.`id`
            AND (`accounts`.`name` = 'test')))
ORDER BY `table1`.`id`
```

Table1 is around 2mln records, accounts is around 30k

Everything is indexed.

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 2,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `name` (`name`),
     KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33261 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `table1` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `order_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
 `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `table1_order_id_index` (`order_id`),
 KEY `member_id_2` (`member_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1985597 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

explain1:

```
+------+--------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table     | type  | possible_keys            | key      | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra                    |
+------+--------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | table1    | index | table1_order_id_index    | PRIMARY  | 4       | NULL  | 1965346 | Using where              |
|    3 | SUBQUERY     | accounts  | ref   | name                     | name     | 767     | const | 1       | Using where; Using index |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED | accounts  | index | PRIMARY,id               | group_id | 4       | NULL  | 32558   | Using index              |
+------+--------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------+
```

explain2:

```
+------+--------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table     | type  | possible_keys            | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                    |
+------+--------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | table1    | index | table1_order_id_index    | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 1965348 | Using where              |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED | accounts  | range | PRIMARY,id,name          | name    | 767     | NULL | 1       | Using where; Using index |
+------+--------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
```

MariaDB 10.1 (downgraded, query 2), -0.5s!

```
+------+--------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table     | type  | possible_keys            | key     | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra                    |
+------+--------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | table1    | index | table1_order_id_index    | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL  | 1974108 | Using where              |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED | accounts  | ref   | PRIMARY,id_2,id,name     | id_2    | 767     | const |       1 | Using where; Using index |
+------+--------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------+
```

Anyone willing to explain me why **separate** **exists** is faster rather than one?

Engine is InnoDB

Comment: I did few simple tests and discovered that the same config on other, better machine, on mariadb 10.1 let that query run in 0.7s, while on mariadb 10.3.3 - 1.2s
+0.5s because I switched version from 10.1 to 10.3.3 ?

Comment: The separate exists means that the queries are different and may return different results. It's no surprise that leads to different execution plans and different performance.

Comment: I know, thank you for answers. I just got to know that there is huge performance difference between 10.1 and 10.3+ mariadb -> 10.1 is faster.

Comment: Your MariaDB example for 10.1 has an extra index id_2 which is used instead of index name. Make sure you have a similar setup when comparing versions

Answer (score 0):

```
EXISTS
         (SELECT *
          FROM `accounts`
          WHERE `accounts`.`name` = 'test' )))
```

probably turned into `TRUE` during the `EXPLAIN`.  It would be a trivial lookup in accounts to check that *some* row had name='test'.

Rerun the first query with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` to be sure that it is not the Query cache tricking you.

Comment: Query cache is off.